# Como mapear uma Lista para outra Lista?

Tags: c#, lista

Como posso mapear uma lista de um tipo para outra lista de outro tipo ?

Estou recebendo uma lista de objeto do tipo

```
public List<DetalheViagem> DetalheViagems { get; set; }
```

E preciso passar os valores para outra lista do tipo.

```
public List<DetalheViagemDto> Viagens { get; set; }
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem ser em loop?

```
passagemAprovadaEdiDto.Viagens = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DetalheViagemDto>()
{
   // Incluir a lista de objeto em vez de fazer um a um ...
   new DetalheViagemDto()
   {

   }
};
```

Comment: `DetalheViagemDto` herda de `DetalheViagem` ou só existem propriedades em comum?

Comment: Só propriedades, mas nem todas estão com o mesmo nome, por exemplos, tenho IdViagem em um e no outro só Id ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) na lista, ele projeta um novo tipo a partir do tipo atual.

**Exemplo:**

```
List<DetalheViagemDto> viagens = detalheViagens.Select(t => 
                                 new DetalheViagemDto
                                 { 
                                   Prop1 = t.Prop1, 
                                   Prop2 = t.Prop2,
                                   /*Etc...*/
                                 }).Tolist();
```